# PHP Connection Error with localhost

Tags: php, localhost

Why do I get this.

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in /usr/local/zend/share/UserServer/s/index.php on line 2

When I do `$con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","root","xxx","s");`?

I've also tried `localhost`, but that didn't work either. I'm positive that the credentials are correct. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure your local host requires a password? try `""` And are you sure you have a database `s` in your mysql?

Comment: default root doesn't require password

Comment: I have a password on root. @kimbarcelona

Comment: I'm sure it has a password, I've used it before and just signed into the database with it, I also have a database `s` @Arian

Comment: @user302975 `mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` what happens when this is on?

Comment: All I get is a `1` @Arian

Comment: @user302975 then you aren't trying in the correct credentials... try `localhost`, with `root` and change root to not use password.

Comment: Then I get `Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1049): Unknown database 's' in /usr/local/zend/share/UserServer/s/index.php on line 2` @Arian

Comment: @user302975 that means you've logged in successfully and there is no database `s`, that's a good sign!

Comment: But I _do_ have a database `s`. I'm looking at it right now.... @Arian

Comment: @user302975 you must be looking at the wrong server... because you are logged in and you don't have a database `s`... it wouldn't lie to you

Comment: I'm running it on my computer. And I only have one instance of MySQL going at the moment.. But then why can I sign into root with phpMyAdmin with my password?... Defiantly bizarre @Arian

Comment: @user302975 the only other thing it can be, is that each user has different database permissions... you might be logged in as a different user than your php code

Comment: Now I get `Warning: mysqli_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known in /usr/local/zend/share/UserServer/s/index.php on line 2`

`Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known in /usr/local/zend/share/UserServer/s/index.php on line 2` When I try using my previous code. @Arian